# Conditional probability when probability is already known of each event.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose I have a bag of 4 marbles($A,B,C$ and $D$). The probability of picking each marble in a given order will be $1/4 \times 1/3 \times 1/2 \times 1/1$. The probability will be the same for all arrangements (A,B,C,D  A,C,B,D etc.) where there are $4!=24$ ways they can be rearranged.

What if for whatever reason (e.g. the marble could have a coating on it that doesn't let me grab it as easy), the probability of me picking the first marble is given. For example $A=0.5, B=0.3, C=0.15$ and $D=0.05$.

How would you work out the probabilities in this case for each arrangement?

Is there even enough information to solve and work out the probabilities the marbles would come out the bag or is more information needed?

Comment: Make yourself a tree-diagram.  Recognize that after a marble has been taken, that changes the probabilities for those that remain... for instance if $A$ was taken in the first pick, in the second pick that leaves $B$ with probability 0.6, $C$ with probability 0.3, and $D$ with probability 0.1, etc...

Comment: I agree with the comment of @JMoravitz, with the qualification that his comment is making an assumption.  He is assuming (for example) that the relative probabilities of B vs C vs D are independent of whether marble A has been removed from the bag.  I (also) regard this assumption as reasonable.  Further, in my opinion, without this assumption, the problem can not be solved.